# glDrawArraysInstanced behave weird when camera move far from the screen

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

What I want to attrive is to render many small quads with this opengl function "glDrawArraysInstanced"， the space between them is the same. For example, please refer to the follwing image:

[image]

The code is as follow:

```
void OpenGLShowVideo::displayBySmallMatrix()
{
    // Now use QOpenGLExtraFunctions instead of QOpenGLFunctions as we want to
    // do more than what GL(ES) 2.0 offers.
    QOpenGLExtraFunctions *f = QOpenGLContext::currentContext()->extraFunctions();
    f->glClearColor(9.f/255.0f, 14.f/255.0f, 15.f/255.0f, 1);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    f->glViewport(0, 0, this->width(), this->height());
    m_displayByMatrixProgram->bind();
    f->glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + m_acRenderToScreenTexUnit);
    f->glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_renderWithMaskFbo->texture());
    if (m_uniformsDirty) {
        m_uniformsDirty = false;
        m_displayByMatrixProgram->setUniformValue(m_samplerLoc, m_acRenderToScreenTexUnit);
        m_proj.setToIdentity();
        m_proj.perspective(INIT_VERTICAL_ANGLE, float(this->width()) / float(this->height()), m_fNearPlane, m_fFarPlane);
        m_displayByMatrixProgram->setUniformValue(m_projMatrixLoc, m_proj);
        QMatrix4x4 camera;
        camera.lookAt(m_eye, m_eye + m_target, QVector3D(0, 1, 0));
        m_displayByMatrixProgram->setUniformValue(m_camMatrixLoc, camera);
        m_world.setToIdentity();
        float fOffsetZ = m_fVerticalAngle / INIT_VERTICAL_ANGLE;
        m_world.translate(m_fMatrixOffsetX, m_fMatrixOffsetY, fOffsetZ);
        m_proj.scale(MATRIX_INIT_SCALE_X, MATRIX_INIT_SCALE_Y, 1.0f);
        m_world.rotate(180, 1, 0, 0);
        QMatrix4x4 wm = m_world;
        m_displayByMatrixProgram->setUniformValue(m_worldMatrixLoc, wm);
        QMatrix4x4 mm;
        mm.setToIdentity();
        m_displayByMatrixProgram->setUniformValue(m_myMatrixLoc, mm);
        m_displayByMatrixProgram->setUniformValue(m_lightPosLoc, QVector3D(0, 0, 70));
        QSize tmpSize = QSize(m_viewPortWidth, m_viewPortHeight);
        m_displayByMatrixProgram->setUniformValue(m_resolutionLoc, tmpSize);
        int whRatioVal = m_viewPortWidth / m_viewPortHeight;
        m_displayByMatrixProgram->setUniformValue(m_whRatioLoc, whRatioVal);
    }
    m_geometries->bindBufferForArraysInstancedDraw();
    f->glDrawArraysInstanced(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4, m_viewPortWidth * m_viewPortHeight);
}
```

And the vertex shader code is as follow:

```
#version 330

layout(location = 0) in vec4 vertex;

out vec3 color;

uniform mat4 mvp_matrix;

uniform mat4 projMatrix;
uniform mat4 camMatrix;
uniform mat4 worldMatrix;
uniform mat4 myMatrix;
uniform vec2 viewResolution;
uniform int whRatio;
uniform sampler2D sampler;

void main() {
    int posX = gl_InstanceID % int(viewResolution.x);
    int posY =  gl_InstanceID / int(viewResolution.y);

    if( posY % whRatio < whRatio) {
        posY = gl_InstanceID / int(viewResolution.x);
    }

    ivec2 pos = ivec2(posX, posY);

   vec2 t = vec2( pos.x * 3.0, pos.y * 3.0  );
   mat4 wm = mat4(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, t.x, t.y, 1, 1) * worldMatrix;

   color = texelFetch(sampler,pos,0).rgb;

   gl_Position = projMatrix * camMatrix * wm * vertex;

}
```

And the fragment shader is as follow:

```
#version 330 core

in  vec3 color;

out  vec4 fragColor;

void main() {
   fragColor = vec4(color, 1.0);
}
```

However, when I move the camera far from the screen (by changing the [camera.lookAt (m_eye, m_eye + m_target, QVector3D (0, 1, 0);] "m_eye" parameter value), I got sth like this:

[image]

The space between quads is different, and the size of the quad is also different. But when I move the camera closer to the screen, it looks much better.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're seeing there is the result of rounding the coordinates to the nearest integer pixel coordinate.

To get something that looks more even, you want to use some form of anti-aliasing. The options that spring to mind are:

1. Enable some sort of full screen anti-aliasing like [MSAA](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Multisampling). This is simple to enable, but can have a significant performance cost.
2. Put your pattern in a texture, and tile that texture over a single quad. [Texture filtering and mip maps](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Sampler_Object#Filtering) should take care of the anti-aliasing for you, and it will probably be faster to render that way as well because you only need a single quad.